# "Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets" was not found in Xamarin project

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I had to format my computer, reinstall all Visual Studio and Xamarin stuff , but after that, my old projects and new ones throws this error:

> The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.14393.0\XamlCompiler\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v14.0\8.21\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets

I can't even understand this error, or find anything in Google. The first file address is different than the second, it doesn't make sense. The second one, is the actual one in my UWP.csproj  and it is in my drive at this location. The first file address I have no idea where it's coming from and it's not in my drive. The 10.0.14393.0 folder doesn't exist in my drive.

Any idea how to understand this problem and fix it?

Thanks

EDIT:
After formatting my computer again and reinstalling the entire Visual Studio/Xamarin suite, I verified that both paths exists in my computer. I wonder what happened.

Comment: are you able to locate this folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v14.0\8.21\` on your PC ?

Comment: Yes, this one I can find and the file is there. The first file address I can't find though.

Comment: Had similar problem. "repairing" Xamarin - In "Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features" Fixed it.

Comment: Try this, create a completely new Blank App, and open its .csproj in text editor. If this file `Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets` is mentioned in the newly created .csproj then copy it's path to your old .csproj file. Then reopen the project

Comment: New Cross-platform projects doesn't even create the UWP project. It throws some pop-up windows with crazy errors. One of them is even blank.

Comment: just thinking out loud not sure but can try replacing first path with the second one in your .csproj manually?

Comment: The path in my .csproj file is pointing to the second path already.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/smondal/2015/08/24/the-imported-project-cprogram-filesx86msbuildmicrosoftwindowsxamlv14-08-1microsoft-windows-ui-xaml-csharp-targets-was-not-found/

Comment: This solution is for Windows Phone, not UWP. I don't want to install Windows Phone tools. It was working without it before and I need to save room in my SSD. But I'll give the first option a try.

Comment: There are two files in the first path by your discription.  `Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks.dll` and  [`Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets`](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/XamlCompiler.git).
You can try to manually build the path to copy these two files

Answer (score 1):

Right click .csproj file on the Solution Explorer that is SampleProject(load failed) then right click select Edit Solution. Once you got there then find TargetPlatformVersion tags, it also has decimal value like this 10.1.17882.0 blablabla something like that... Then Open folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin you will see version SDK folders there, then copy FOLDER NAME of the latest version SDK folder and PASTE or replace value 10.1.17882.0 in TargetPlatformVersion tags SAME with TargetPlatformMinVersion tags but lower version of SDK on the .csproj file. Right click and reload project cheers!